# how to divide a double word number by a word number?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

am finding problem in dividing this number (23160148h) by(0026h)
this is my code

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data

x dd 23160148h
sum dw ?

.code
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

mov ax,x
mov dx,x+2
mov bx,0026h
div bx


mov sum,ax
mov sum+2,dx

end
```

when I run this program I get an error that says division error (overflow )

any one have an idea about what's wrong with it ?
note : am working on assembly 8086

Comment: The quotient, `0x23160148 / 0x26 = 0xec5e59`, doesn't fit in AX, so `div` raises a #DE error.  http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/DIV.html.  You need extended-precision division to avoid overflow.

Comment: and how do I do this?

Comment: Found a duplicate which shows how to use two `div` instructions to get a 32-bit quotient and 16-bit remainder from 32b / 16b division.

Comment: For constants, multiply instead of dividing. For example (for 32-bit unsigned integers), `x/26 == x * 1/26 == (x * (1<<32)/26) >> 32 == (x * 0x9D89D8A) >> 32`.